# Datediff & Group By not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, group-by, datediff

I'm trying to build a query (QueryB) for it to be referenced in my MS Access control. I know I got the source expression syntax right, I have a very similar working control with QueryA.

I only changed the field and query names. However I keep getting the infamous `#Name?` error with QueryB. The difference between QueryA and QueryB is the SQL code. QueryA has a `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` and QueryB only has `DATEDIFF()`. I have tried adding the `GROUP BY` to QueryB, but kept getting [...execute query does not include the specified expression  as part of aggregate function].

Query B:

```
SELECT IIF(DATEDIFF("d",Date_X,Date_Y)>100),
ROUND(IIF(DATEDIFF("d",Date_X,Date_Y)/30,2),
DATEDIFF("d",Date_X,Date_Y) 
AS DATEDIFF_X_Y
FROM LAB_DATES GROUP BY LAB_DATES.ID;
```

This is in MS Access SQL.

ControlB source referencing QueryB in MS Access:

```
=DLookUp("[DATE_DIFF_X_Y]",
         "[QueryB]",
         "[LAB_DATES.ID] = " & [Forms]![Lab Results Form]![Textbox_DATE_ID])
```

When taking out the `GROUP BY`, this query runs fine but I get the `#Name?` error in the control. All data is from ODBC MySQL. Access is the front end.

**Edit:** I can just drop `GROUP BY`. But I will get the `#Name?` error. My goal is to display the date difference between Date_X and Date_Y.

Comment: DATE is a reserved word in MS Access, that could be your trouble.

Comment: Sorry, I was substituting words from my actual queries. (DATE isn't acutally used.) I will edit it to LabDate.

Answer (score 0):

> [...execute query does not include the specified expression as part
>   of aggregate function]

That error message already indicates that using GROUP BY does not work with aggregate Functions.

`DATEDIFF()` is an aggregate function and does not work with a `GROUP BY`.

The reason for that is that `GROUP BY` reduces your dataresult and only displays one line per different entry of the column you are using.

What is your aim for that query anyways? I am sure there is a different solumtion for that problem. `GROUP BY DATE.ID` sounds like you are making a `GROUP BY` on the primary key which has no effect, because primary keys are unique per definition.

Comment: `DATEDIFF` is not an aggregate function. The `DATEDIFF` needs to be contained within an aggregate function, or within the group by. I do however agree with your point that grouping by `DATE.ID` seems redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My query is used to subtract dates X and Y and further converts them to months if the amount of days is >100. I will have separate event functions to create Labelboxes based off the unit of the number (days or months) so the numbers wont be ambiguous.

**Edit:** As for the GROUP BY ID, I suspect the control is trying to display all records instead of the current one in the form.

Comment: I can just drop `GROUP BY`. But I will get the `#Name?` error. My goal is to display the date difference between Date_X and Date_Y.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is within your `DLookup` rather than your query. You do not need the `GROUP BY` at all, this will cause the query to error, you can simply make QueryB:

```
SELECT  IIF(DATEDIFF("d",Date_X,Date_Y)>100),
            ROUND(IIF(DATEDIFF("d",Date_X,Date_Y)/30,2),
            DATEDIFF("d",Date_X,Date_Y) AS DATEDIFF_X_Y
FROM    LAB_DATES;
```

The problem is that in your `DLookup` you are using:

```
[LAB_DATES.ID]
```

Where you actually want

```
[LAB_DATES].[ID]
```

i.e. In it's current form you are looking for a column called `LAB_DATES.ID` rather than a Column called `ID` in the object `LAB_DATES`. Changing your `DLookup` to this:

```
=DLookUp("[DATE_DIFF_X_Y]",
         "[QueryB]",
         "[LAB_DATES].[ID] = " & [Forms]![Lab Results Form]![Textbox_DATE_ID])
```

Should do the trick.